# Raspberry Pi GPIO: Change Duty Cycle By Console Commands

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, gpio

After implementing a python-script that changes duty-cycle for a LED like in this example:

http://raspi.tv/2013/rpi-gpio-0-5-2a-now-has-software-pwm-how-to-use-it

I would like to change duty-cycle in the shell or console, what commands and in what order do they have to be keyed in?

I've done little research so far that brought me to a similar example done with python like in the link above. I also know how to execute console-commands in PHP.

My intention is to take advantage of console-commands to control the brightness of a LED that is triggered by a AJAX To PHP Request. I do not want to execute a python-script in PHP because of right-privileges on Apache2-Server having to be adjusted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the meanwhile there is the possibility of directly sending PWM signals with PHP using the [php-pigpio library](https://github.com/Volantus/php-pigpio/blob/master/docs/sending-pwm-signals.md), which is an interface for the Pigpio daemon

**Pulse width:**

Sending an PWM signal with a pulse width of 1500 microseconds on GPIO pin 15:

```
use Volantus\Pigpio\Client;
use Volantus\Pigpio\PWM\PwmSender;

$client = new Client();
$sender = new PwmSender($client);
$sender->setPulseWidth(15, 1500);
```

**Duty cycle:**

Of if you prefer the duty cycle / range mode (as in your own example):

Setting the range to 1024:

```
$sender->setRange(15, 1024);
```

Sending a signal of 50%:

```
$sender->setDutyCycle(15, 512);
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally it was not as hard as I thought it would be. Despite the fact that Raspberry-PI B+ has got a lot of PIN's it has only got one PIN (GPIO 18 = Pin 12) **PWM** can be controlled via console by. These are the commands to control Duty Cycle for GPIO-Pin 18:

1. Tell PIN 18 to be an Output-PIN for **PWM**:

   ```
   gpio -1 mode 12 pwm
   ```

   or

   ```
   gpio -g mode 18 pwm
   ```
2. PWM has got a range between 0-1023

   0 switches a LED off:

   ```
   gpio -1 pwm 12 0
   ```

   or

   ```
   gpio -g pwm 18 0
   ```

   1023 makes LED to emit max brightness:

   ```
   gpio -1 pwm 12 1023
   ```

   or

   ```
   gpio -g pwm 18 1023
   ```

Deeply interesting that you do not have to tell the PIN on what frequency it should use **PWM** and my LED does not even flicker.

Hopes it helps someone out there.